# How to store copy each row from one table into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which scans all tables in my DB for a certain column (codevalues).
It then prints the distinct values for that column and its table it belongs in.
Each column can belong to many tables.
i.e. codeX can be found in Table A and Table B.

```
ActualCode in TableA

ActualCode
----------
0
1
2

(3 row(s) affected)

--------------------
ActualCode in TableB

ActualCode
----------
 0

(1 row(s) affected)
```

I am trying to figure out how to scan each row in my results, and then insert that row into a new table in a new database.
For example, i want to grab 0 from below for TableA, and insert a row into a new table and store the Value(0) and the Table name (TableA)

And then do the same for value 1...2 etc, and then repeat the same for the next table.

My query is as this:

```
 DECLARE cursorColumnNames CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME FROM 
 INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%ActualCode%' AND TABLE_CATALOG = 'db1' AND  COLUMN_NAME NOT 
 IN(select  ColumnName from [DataDictionary].[dbo].[Code])

 OPEN cursorColumnNames
 FETCH NEXT FROM cursorColumnNames INTO @columnName, @tableName;
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT @columnName + ' in ' + @tableName;
        PRINT '  '
        SET @SqlQuery = 'SELECT  DISTINCT '  + @columnName  + ' FROM ' + @tableName;
        EXEC (@SqlQuery);
        PRINT '--------------------'
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursorColumnNames INTO @columnName, @tableName;
    END;

CLOSE cursorColumnNames;
DEALLOCATE cursorColumnNames;
```

I tried grabbing each top 1 value and then add that and repeat until all data has been transferred.
But my query looks for columns that are not in the second db so after the first iteration, my query returns 0 records.

So i am confused as what to do or try.

I do not want to create a new table, the table already exists.
The table i want to add the individual rows to is defined as this:

```
  CodeInsertID      TableName   ColumnName  CodeNo
  4648              TableA      ActualCode  0
  4647              TableA      ActualCode  1
  4646              TableA      ActualCode  2
  4645              TableB      ActualCode  0
```

Answer (score 1):

can u try like this ? its work for me.

```
Declare @SqlQuery nvarchar(max),
@columnName nvarchar(50),
@tableName nvarchar(50)

Declare @table table (TableName nvarchar(50) , ColumnName nvarchar(50) , CodeNo int)

DECLARE cursorColumnNames CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%ActualCode%' AND TABLE_CATALOG = 'db1' AND  COLUMN_NAME NOT 
IN(select  ColumnName from [DataDictionary].[dbo].[Code])


OPEN cursorColumnNames
FETCH NEXT FROM cursorColumnNames INTO @columnName, @tableName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --PRINT @columnName + ' in ' + @tableName;
    --PRINT '  '
    SET @SqlQuery = 'SELECT  DISTINCT ''' + @tablename+ ''', '''+ @columnName+ ''' , ' + @columnName + ' FROM  [' + @tableName + ']';
    PRINT @SqlQuery
    INSERT INTO @table (TableName,ColumnName,CodeNo)
    EXEC (@SqlQuery);
    --PRINT '--------------------'
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorColumnNames INTO @columnName, @tableName;
END;

CLOSE cursorColumnNames;
DEALLOCATE cursorColumnNames;

SELECT * from @table
```

Comment: that idea is good but i do not want to create a table on the fly. The new table exists already and i need to add it like such :   
INSERT INTO [DataDictionary].[dbo].[Code]
           ([CodeInsertDateTime]
           ,[ColumnInsertID]
           ,[TableName]
           ,ColumnName
           ,[CodeNo]
           ,[Definition]
           ,[Description])

Comment: you can change insert table, i declared @table because display the result. U need just referance from insert into block

Comment: could you explain? i tried but it does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Cursors are really slow, you can do this in one single dynamic statement, which we can build in one shot.

You also need to quote the column and table names with `QUOTENAME` otherwise your code may not work.

**Note:** To escape a single quote `'` in a string, use `''`. Don't get confused about which code is part of the dynamic section and which part is static.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) =
N'INSERT INTO myTABLE (TableName, ColumnName, CodeNo)
' +

(SELECT STRING_AGG(

    N'SELECT 
    N' + QUOTENAME(t.name, '''') + N',
    N' + QUOTENAME(c.name, '''') + N',
    CAST(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + N' AS nvarchar(max))    -- or whatever your column type is here
  FROM db1.' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name),

  CAST(N'
UNION ALL
' AS nvarchar(max))

FROM db1.sys.tables t
JOIN db1.sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
JOIN db1.sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE N'%ActualCode%'
    AND c.name NOT IN (SELECT ColumnName FROM [DataDictionary].[dbo].[Code])
);

-- PRINT @sql; -- for testing

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

---

You say you only have SQL Server 2014, so you would have to use either a cursor or `FOR XML PATH`. You can still build the query, then execute it in one shot:

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) =
N'INSERT INTO myTABLE (TableName, ColumnName, CodeNo)
';

DECLARE @cur CURSOR;
SET @cur = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT 

    N'SELECT 
    N' + QUOTENAME(t.name, '''') + N',
    N' + QUOTENAME(c.name, '''') + N',
    CAST(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + N' AS nvarchar(max))    -- or whatever your column type is here
  FROM db1.' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)

FROM db1.sys.tables t
JOIN db1.sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
JOIN db1.sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE N'%ActualCode%'
    AND c.name NOT IN (SELECT ColumnName FROM [DataDictionary].[dbo].[Code])
;

OPEN @cur;

DECLARE @tableSql nvarchar(max);

FETCH NEXT FROM @cur INTO @tableSql;
SET @sql = @sql + @tableSql;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM @cur INTO @tableSql;
    SET @sql = @sql + N'
UNION ALL
' + @tableSql;
END;

-- PRINT @sql; -- for testing

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

There is no need to close or deallocate as it's a local variable and will be closed automatically at the end of the batch

Comment: I see your point but the table i want to add the data to already exists and is in another DB. Also, my script will be ran monthly, so i would not want to create a table each time.

Comment: Confused, I'm not creating the table, there is just an `insert`

Comment: But what do the variables inside the INSERT reflect? I do not see them referencing anything? Should it not be INSERT into 'DB" VALUES ('X', 'Y'....'Z')?

Comment: No, if you use the `PRINT @sql` line you will see that the result of the dynamic build is actually an `INSERT ... SELECT ...` statement i.e. it inserts all results from all tables in one statement

Comment: oh ok..when i try and run it i get the following error :
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 27
Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".

Comment: I take it you are not on SQL Server 2017+ then?

Comment: No i have to use 2014

Comment: Ok, on the FAST FORWARD part it throws an error :

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'FAST_FORWARD'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 21
Must declare the scalar variable "@cur".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 25
Must declare the scalar variable "@cur".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 30
Must declare the scalar variable "@cur".

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ''.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near ''.

Comment: Fixed that also now

Comment: No errors now but its been running for 4 minutes and nothing happening.

Comment: I wonder which bit is taking a long time, the build phase or the `exec` phase. Try running everything up to, not including `exec...`. If it's the build phase, we can switch to `FOR XML PATH`

Comment: it just says executing query for a long time so i had to cancel it

Comment: Ok so when i run everything apart from EXEC, it runs fast and says "Command(s) completed successfully."

Comment: Hum I guess you just got a lot of rows to insert then. Perhaps add a `WITH (TABLOCK)` hint to the insert table, might speed it up a bit

Comment: not really, should only  be 5 or 6 rows added. WITH (TABLOCK) doesnt speed it up. Could it be what is being specified in the INSERT?

Comment: I suggest you check the actual code with `PRINT @sql` and see it conforms to your expectation: perhaps there are other unexpected tables it is including. Or perhaps you need an extra `WHERE` filter on the dynamic query

Comment: The print returns this:

INSERT INTO [DataDictionary].[dbo].[Code] WITH (TABLOCK) (TableName, ColumnName, CodeNo)
SELECT 
    N'LIMITS_OF_INSURANCE',
    N'ActualCode',
    CAST([ActualCode] AS nvarchar(max))    -- or whatever your column type is here
  FROM cover.[dbo].[LIMITS_OF_INSURANCE]
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    N'LIMITS_OF_INSURANCE',
    N'ActualCode',
    CAST([ActualCode] AS nvarchar(max))    -- or whatever your column type is here
  FROM cover.[dbo].[LIMITS_OF_INSURANCE]


In the table i am adding to there is more columns than the three mentioned. Would this be the issue?

Comment: I wonder why it's got the same table and column twice. Also, what is the column type you need? If it's not `nvarchar(max)` you should change it. Can you [edit] your question and detail your actual source and target table definitions, and which columns you are trying to clone. `CREATE TABLE` statements please.